# Search by tag name and category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search

How can I return all posts that match a specific taxonomy using `<?php get_search_form(); ?>`

For example: if a user enters a search query that matches the name of a tag or category, `search.php` will return all posts with a matching tag, or that fall into a matching category. I am working with a custom post type, and as of now, `get_search_form();` seems to only return matches based on content and title alone. Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: If somebody types in a tag or category, do you only want the posts with that tag/category, or do you want to include the regular search results in addition to the tag/category results?

Comment: Have a look at the [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

use this function put in function.php file for cat=22 filter   change your cat id for you mind

```
function my_search_form( $form ) { 

    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:') . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
   <input type="text" value="22" name="cat" id="scat" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Search') .'" />
    </div>
    </form>';

    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );
```